# Any other method available in libgdx for android than "Gdx.input.istouched()" method?

Tags: android, libgdx

can someone explain me this.I need to know whether any other methods can be implemented to deal with user touch inputs instead of "Gdx.input.istouched()" 
Iam a noob and learning android game development using libgdx.I have used above method which is not satisfied for the desired output.Is there anyone to help.I will share my code if so

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what you are trying to accomplish. Why doesn't the method satisfy your needs? And perhaps provide the code you are using.

Comment: Take a look at here.I have asked in details with code https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/146147/104336

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own `InputProcessor` and use that to catch **all** touch events.

```
public class YourGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    public void create() {
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputProcessor() {
            @Override
            public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
                // Handle touch up here
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
                // Handle dragging here
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
                // Handle touch down here
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: in touchdragged(), how can i drag a texture.

Comment: actually, i want to drag textures only to specified location

Comment: none of the tutorials on internet explaining briefly.For a beginers like me,its hard to understand.

Comment: @iamsajidshaz_aa If I find some time I'll knock up an example of how you can drag textures around.